# Is Vue Routing can be used for building complex directory based apps with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I need to develop the directory based app in laravel using vue js.
I was wondering that SPA is a good approach to build complex apps using vue routing.
If so then will it cause for google crawlers to crawl the pages which based on vue routing.

Any helping material?